# fox:alt-text not allowed to appear in element 'fo:external-graphic'."

Tags: apache-fop

I'm trying to add the alternate text into my images just as the Apache FOP documentation instructs: By using `fox-alt:-text`.

```xml
<fo:external-graphic src="logo.gif" content-width="75%" content-height="75%" fox:alt-text="My company logo"/>
```

I'm using Apache FOP version 2.5 and accessibility is ON (setted true in fop.xconf). For some reason I'm getting an error message saying

```xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'fox:alt-text' is not allowed to appear in element 'fo:external-graphic'.
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: Is the namespace fox: declared?

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I now realized that the problem is not in Apache FOP but it's in my code. Our system is doing some addition schema validation (javax.xml.validation.Validator) against the plain fo schema and doesn't see the fox extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now realized that the problem is not in Apache FOP but it's in my code. Our system is doing some additional schema validation (javax.xml.validation.Validator) against the plain fo schema and doesn't see the fox extension.

*fox:alt-text is* not a part of the original fo schema's *fo:external-graphic* definition and is causing validation failures.